# where to find 簡筆字?

Tags: traditional-characters, character-variant

I'm learning traditional Chinese, and have heard/seen examples of 簡筆字, like how 聽 can often be written as ⿰口耳 in Taiwan.  Every time I try to look this up, I just get directed to the same Quora thread mentioning it, the Ryakuji wikipedia page, and 簡體字.  Now I realize that there can be similarities between 簡筆字 and 簡體字, but there also are differences, case and point with 聽.

So I was wondering if there were any resource on their use, where they are used, how they are used, as well as a reference to common practices.  Like does 門 become 门 in Taiwanese 簡筆字 like in 簡體字 or Japanese Ryakuji, or is it always written 門.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for: [繁體俗字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E7%B9%81%E9%AB%94%E4%BF%97%E5%AD%97). Perhaps especially the "其他臺港俗字" section; here's a quick snippet:

> [image]

---

This article on [Daily View](https://dailyview.tw/Popular/Detail/10205) is also quite interesting. They talk of a couple other examples:

> **「台式簡體」融合各式寫法　與中國簡體有所不同**
> .
> 這些台灣人自己發明的「台式簡體」又可稱為「繁體俗字」，大多是來自古文、日本漢字，也有些是從古文、日本漢字、中國簡體字變形，成為許多台灣人約定俗成的字，像是「転（轉）」、「亇（個）」、「奌（點）」、「対（對）」，另外還有人會將「聽」寫作「咡」，可能是受「口耳之學」成語影響。
>
> 很多人會誤以為「台式簡體」就是中國簡字體，事實上兩者不太一樣，所以並非將繁體字簡化就是中國簡體字。不過在填寫較正式的文件時，通常還是得使用繁體字。很多人看了網友的解釋後都表示「看了這篇長知識」、「原來是台式簡體」。

A fun picture as well:

> [image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!  Is there a searchable online resource were I can find and learn them?

Comment: @Tosaku The wiki page has most of what you're looking for. Check the "其他臺港俗字" section and the reference links.

Answer (score 1):

I found these pages that might help you:

- [https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/简笔字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E7%AE%80%E7%AC%94%E5%AD%97)
- [https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/繁體俗字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E7%B9%81%E9%AB%94%E4%BF%97%E5%AD%97)

Answer (score 0):

> ...like how 聽 can often be written as ⿰口耳 in Taiwan.

Wrong. Both the 簡(寫)字(taiwan) and 簡體字(mainland) for 聽(繁字/繁體字) is 听 = 口 + 斤.

簡體字 is used exclusively in China. Its use in Taiwan is up to personal choice except rarely seen in formal publications and government documents/communications.

Comment: User Mou某's answer seems to indicate that 咡 is indeed sometimes used instead of 听

Comment: @JohnFrazer Follow this link to see what 咡 means https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%92%A1.

Comment: @JohnFrazer Japanese 漢字 - 咡 https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjiy/13304.html (see content using google translate if you don't know Japanese.)

Comment: It's apparently short hand used by Taiwanese students.

Comment: @Tosaku I came from Taiwan and used to write shorthand all the time, but never ever heard of or seen its uses.

Comment: No doubt. It's probably a recent coinage, or maybe is old, but from a part of Taiwan you didn't interact much with.

Comment: @Tosaku Maybe 30 years in Taiwan wasn't long enough. Will you bother to look it up in a dictionary or find literature about its use? I'll greatly appreciate your effort in keeping me updated.

Comment: @r13 This guy who answered is a University professor in Taiwan. He mentions he sees it in his students journals.

Comment: Just for the record, of course @r13 is not wrong to point out the usual sources which unanimously state that 咡 is to be read er and to signify 'cheek'. That said, it's a rare and obscure character and it wouldn't be unheard of that some such characters are unwittingly re-created in form only at a much later time, just by combining some high-frequency components, and to be taken to mean something else entirely—if the sources can be shown to be reliable.

Comment: @JohnFrazer The academics would be fast to point out the use of an existing word, albeit rarely known, to be a simplified word for the other word of a different meaning is an unacceptable mistake. Thanks for your kind comment.

Comment: @Tosaku Can you give me his and the college's name? I will track it.

Comment: @Tosaku "另外還有人**會將**聽寫作咡，可能是受「口耳之學」成語影響." Here is my sentence to show what **會將** means - 有人**會將**  驢指作馬.